# What are the brain chemicals associated with food cravings? Possible to treat it by manipulating brain chemicals?

Tags: brain, feeding

It is frequently mentioned that physical factors such as hormonal imbalances have an impact on brain chemicals, especially when it comes to food cravings ([source](https://foodslop.com/the-secrets-of-food-cravings/)). What are the brain chemicals associated with food cravings, and is it possible to alleviate or treat food cravings by manipulating these brain chemicals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain brain chemicals, or neurotransmitters, have been associated with the sensation of craving and consumption of food. The primary ones include:

- Dopamine: This is often referred to as the "reward" neurotransmitter.
  When we eat foods that we enjoy, our brains release dopamine,
  creating a pleasurable sensation. This can create a reward feedback
  loop that makes us crave those foods in the future.
- Serotonin: This neurotransmitter is associated with feelings of
  happiness and well-being. Certain foods, especially those high in
  carbohydrates, can increase serotonin levels and thus make us feel
  good, promoting further cravings for these foods.
- Ghrelin: This is a hormone rather than a neurotransmitter, but it
  plays a key role in stimulating appetite. It's often referred to as
  the "hunger hormone."
- Leptin: This hormone acts as a counterpart to ghrelin. It sends
  signals to the brain indicating that we're full and should stop
  eating.
- Endorphins: These neurotransmitters are the body's natural
  painkillers and can create feelings of euphoria. Certain foods,
  particularly those high in sugar and fat, can trigger endorphin
  release.
- Neuropeptide Y: This is a potent appetite stimulant released by the
  hypothalamus.
- Insulin: This hormone also regulates hunger and satiety signals. When
  insulin levels are imbalanced, it can lead to strong food cravings,
  especially for sugar.
- Glutamate: This neurotransmitter plays a role in the neural
  stimulation of specific food cravings.

Manipulating brain chemicals to control food cravings is a complex process, as these chemicals interact intricately. However, certain treatments and strategies aim to influence these interactions. Medications, like SSRIs, can increase serotonin levels in the brain, helping reduce cravings. Lifestyle changes, such as regular exercise and a balanced diet, can also impact these brain chemicals, helping stabilize them and reduce cravings. But it's important to remember that these approaches vary in effectiveness for different individuals, and a comprehensive approach considering psychological and social factors is necessary for controlling cravings.